# Text Alignment Bottom keeps text at top of screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have got text overlaid onto an image and I am trying to get the text to be on the bottom of the image. I have tried using the different variations of `alignment: Alignment.bottom` but if I add `end` it just puts the text to the far right on the top of the image, not the bottom:

```
               return new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                              new Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: Colors.pink[250],
                                    width: 7,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
                                ),
                                  child: new Container(
                                    child: new Image.asset(dateIdeas[index]['Image']),
                                  ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                child: Text(dateIdeas[index]['Description'],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 30,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontFamily: 'IndieFlower',
                                    )),
                              ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                );
```

I am not sure if I am just missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your text's Container width and height is not the same as your image's. Since you're using a `Stack`, use the `Positioned.fill` widget to create a container over the image that is the same size as it.

Something like:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(), // Your image here
    Positioned.fill(
      child: Container(), // Your text with alignment here
    ),
  ]
),
```

Comment: Thanks! I am going to mark this as the correct answer, but I had to add the Text widget below the image widget because of how widgets behave in a Stack: https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-stack-in-flutter-3264619b3a77

Comment: Hello @CJW my answer below was correct, at least you could upvote? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample app to write "Hello" to the bottom of an image:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Image.network("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586924234039-d0f3b6dcab92?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80")
          ),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Text("Hello", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
          ),),
        ]),),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```